# Why are my postgres logical replication workers crashing after syncing a certain amount of data?

Tags: postgresql, transactional-replication, aws, docker

I am trying to setup a logical replication between two postgresql 12 DBs run in Docker containers on AWS ECS. I gave the task 2 vCPU and 6 GB of ram so quite luxurious for a DB with ~1e7 rows in two tables.

When I start the service the workers for the two tables connect and start to sync. But for some reason the worker are always terminated after around 9e6 rows.

Does anyone know why this happening and to fix this? Every hint is appreciated :)

I created the publication on the master with this:

```
CREATE ROLE replicate WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE PUBLICATION pub FOR TABLE public.product, public.merchant ;
GRANT SELECT ON public.product, public.merchant TO replicate;
ALTER ROLE replicate WITH REPLICATION;
ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level = logical;
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

And the subscription with this:

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION subs
    CONNECTION 'hostaddr=[ip] port=5432 dbname=[name] user=replicate password=password'
    PUBLICATION pub
    WITH (slot_name=subs, create_slot=false);
```

This is the log:

```
2020-08-07 13:04:15.357 UTC [1] LOG: database system is shut down
2020-08-07 13:04:09.806 UTC [1] LOG: background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 82) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-07 13:04:09.806 UTC [74] LOG: shutting down
2020-08-07 13:04:09.798 UTC [1] LOG: background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 79) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-07 13:04:09.798 UTC [82] FATAL: terminating logical replication worker due to administrator command
2020-08-07 13:04:09.798 UTC [82] CONTEXT: COPY product, line 8567000
2020-08-07 13:04:09.798 UTC [1] LOG: background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 80) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-07 13:04:09.796 UTC [80] FATAL: terminating logical replication worker due to administrator command
2020-08-07 13:04:09.573 UTC [1] LOG: received smart shutdown request
2020-08-07 13:03:46.380 UTC [74] LOG: checkpoints are occurring too frequently (29 seconds apart)
2020-08-07 13:03:46.380 UTC [74] HINT: Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2020-08-07 13:02:10.358 UTC [74] LOG: checkpoints are occurring too frequently (29 seconds apart)
2020-08-07 13:02:10.358 UTC [74] HINT: Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2020-08-07 13:01:44.650 UTC [81] LOG: logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "subs", table "merchant" has finished
2020-08-07 13:01:42.591 UTC [82] LOG: logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "subs", table "product" has started
2020-08-07 13:01:42.581 UTC [81] LOG: logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "subs", table "merchant" has started
2020-08-07 13:01:41.359 UTC [80] LOG: logical replication apply worker for subscription "subs" has started
2020-08-07 13:01:41.353 UTC [1] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
2020-08-07 13:01:41.348 UTC [73] LOG: database system was shut down at 2020-08-07 13:01:41 UTC
2020-08-07 13:01:41.349 UTC [73] LOG: recovered replication state of node 1 to 0/0
2020-08-07 13:01:41.333 UTC [1] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-08-07 13:01:41.329 UTC [1] LOG: starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-07 13:01:41.329 UTC [1] LOG: listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2020-08-07 13:01:41.329 UTC [1] LOG: listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
done
server stopped
2020-08-07 13:01:41.246 UTC [45] LOG: database system is shut down
waiting for server to shut down....2020-08-07 13:01:41.220 UTC [45] LOG: aborting any active transactions
2020-08-07 13:01:41.221 UTC [45] LOG: background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 52) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-07 13:01:41.222 UTC [71] FATAL: terminating logical replication worker due to administrator command
2020-08-07 13:01:41.223 UTC [45] LOG: background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 71) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-07 13:01:41.223 UTC [47] LOG: shutting down
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION
2020-08-07 13:01:41.217 UTC [71] LOG: logical replication apply worker for subscription "subs" has started
2020-08-07 13:01:41.217 UTC [45] LOG: received fast shutdown request
ALTER TABLE
CREATE INDEX
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE TABLE
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
set_config
------------
(1 row)
SET
SET
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
CREATE DATABASE
done
server started
2020-08-07 13:01:39.951 UTC [45] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
2020-08-07 13:01:39.947 UTC [46] LOG: database system was shut down at 2020-08-07 13:01:39 UTC
2020-08-07 13:01:39.929 UTC [45] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
waiting for server to start....2020-08-07 13:01:39.927 UTC [45] LOG: starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
syncing data to disk ... ok
Success. You can now start the database server using:
pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
creating configuration files ... ok
selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default max_connections ... 100
The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
Data page checksums are disabled.
fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.
```

Answer (score 0):

> LOG: received smart shutdown request

Someone sent the server a shutdown signal.  Generally it would need to be 'root', or the owner of the server process (usually 'postgres') to do that.